# Port Knocking UDP with Javascript in Browser

Tags: javascript, html, browser, webrtc

So I am trying to send a port knock sequence from javascript.

The TCP part is simple enough with websockets.

I've read that WebRTC is the closest thing the browser offers to sending a UDP packet... but WebRTC is a lot to digest just to attempt to send a UDP "knock".

Is it even possible to "knock" via UDP using WebRTC?  If so, please provide a simple example.  I am just looking for a simplistic working example.  I.e. to "knock" via TCP you can use the following:

```
var sock = new WebSocket("ws://"+ host +":"+ port);
```

Comment: No, it is not possible to send UDP packets from a browser.

Comment: @symcbean I would disagree with that statement. It is possible to send UDP packets from a browser.

Comment: @wpp: your example *does not send UDP from the browser* - it creats a custom extension which runs in the browser. It is also possible to acheive this result using ActiveX or Java - but it requires installation of a custom component on the client.

Comment: @symcbean My example does not create an extension. It uses WebRTC ICE Gathering (which sends UDP packets in order to determine the possible candidates for a media-session). Or am I misunderstanding something?

Comment: It is worth to note that port knocking is vulnerable to the network's traffic sniffing since the knock sequence is not encrypted. There are some approaches to counter that vulnerability [cryptoknock](https://github.com/Jiab77/cryptknock), [fwknop](https://www.usenix.org/system/files/login/articles/1063-fwknop.pdf), [sKnock](https://www.net.in.tum.de/fileadmin/bibtex/publications/papers/sknock.pdf). However none of them is designed to work from within a web browser.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is in fact possible to send UDP packets with the browser.

You could either write a chrome extension (app) which would give you access to https://developer.chrome.com/apps/sockets_udp (`"sockets": {...}` in your manifest.json).

Or, as far as WebRTC goes:

```
var pc = new webkitRTCPeerConnection(
    { "iceServers": [{ "url": "stun:localhost:1234" }] }
);

pc.createOffer(function (sessionDescription) {
    pc.setLocalDescription(sessionDescription);

}, function(error) {
    alert(error);
}, { 'mandatory': { 'OfferToReceiveAudio': true, 'OfferToReceiveVideo': true } });
```

And a quick ruby-script

require 'socket'

```
$port = 1234

t = Thread.start do
  server = UDPSocket.open
  server.bind(nil, $port)
  4.times do
    a = server.recvfrom(12364)
    p a
    p server.send "ping", 0, a[1][2], a[1][1]
  end
end

t.join
```

> ["\x00\x01\x00\x00!\x12\xA4B0PgJcgcqalrO", ["AF_INET", 51881, "192.168.0.27", "192.168.0.27"]]
>   4
>   ["\x00\x01\x00\x00!\x12\xA4Bbmfxf2ABsZws", ["AF_INET", 53092, "192.168.0.27", "192.168.0.27"]]
>   4
>   ["\x00\x01\x00\x00!\x12\xA4B0PgJcgcqalrO", ["AF_INET", 51881, "192.168.0.27", "192.168.0.27"]]
>   4
>   ["\x00\x01\x00\x00!\x12\xA4Bbmfxf2ABsZws", ["AF_INET", 53092, "192.168.0.27", "192.168.0.27"]]

I'm not sure though if that qualifies as "port knock sequence."

Ref: https://www.webrtc-experiment.com/docs/webrtc-for-beginners.html